# Validate to prevent a path string to go up to parent folder

Tags: c#, string, security, path, filesystems

My business logic is accepting a folder path string to read a folder/file. However as security dictates, the user can only access that folder. For example:

Their folder is: C:\foo\user\bar, they can access `C:\foo\user\bar\data\.a.b..txt` by https://www.example.com/download?path=data/.a.b..txt

However, I want to prevent user from entering something that could make them go up a folder and see data of other. Here is my current code:

```
        var result = this.ResultFolder; // The user folder (\user\bar as in the example)

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            path = path.Replace("/", @"\");

            if (path.StartsWith(@"\"))
            {
                path = path.Substring(1);
            }

            if (path.StartsWith('\\') || path.Contains("..\\"))
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("Forbidden Path.");
            }

            result = Path.Combine(result, path);
        }
```

Basically, what I do:

- Replace all / into \ so I only have to worry about one separation character.
- The request allows path to start with \ , it counts as nothing.
- Now if user try to be malicious (by using `\\` to go to root directory), or trying to go up a level by using `..\` (note before I used `..` only, but get false case because it is valid file/folder name)

Is it correct and safe yet? Is there any framework method that helps with this?

Comment: You will still get a false negative for "a\b..\c.txt". Do you have to worry about symbolic links or hard links?

Comment: Consider using `Path.GetFullPath(string path)` and then compare the root folders of the result to make sure that it matches what you expect your root to be.  It handles absolute paths, relative paths, paths with "`..`" in them, and comes up with a full path to whatever the result is.

Comment: Why not just remove the users rights from the parent folder?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I have thought about this, but as we developers will not be the same one deploying them, this is an additional precaution step. Also, this one will be served as a IIS website, so even if we set read permission for folder only, the user can still try to get data of other user (since the same process serves the files for all users).

Comment: @KlausGütter Just simple file access for now, so they are not of our concerns right now. Will fix the false negative, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Flydog57 I think this would be the best approach at the moment. Is there any special case that may happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `Path.GetFullPath(string path)`:

Create this function:

```
private static bool VerifyPathUnderRoot(string pathToVerify, string rootPath = ".")
{
    var fullRoot = Path.GetFullPath(rootPath);
    var fullPathToVerify = Path.GetFullPath(pathToVerify);
    return fullPathToVerify.StartsWith(fullRoot);
}
```

Then you can test it with code like this:

```
 var paths = new[]
 {
     "somepath/somefile.xxx",
     "..\\somepath/somefile.xxx",
     @"C:\this\that\the.other",
 };
 foreach (var path in paths)
 {
     var isOk = VerifyPathUnderRoot(path);
     var okString = isOk ? "OK" : "No";
     Debug.WriteLine($"{okString}: {path}");
 }
```

which results in this in the Output pane of the debugger:

```
OK: somepath/somefile.xxx
No: ..\somepath/somefile.xx
No: C:\this\that\the.other
```

I use `GetFullPath` twice to canonicalize the paths (making sure that all slashes end up the same, etc.).